# How make current_user admin in update query in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am using somewhat like

```
current_user.update_attributes(:admin=> '1')
```

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. Your questions needs some editing to be informative enough for people to understand what you want and what you tried ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome at Stackoverflow. Your "question" is quite basic and you do not state whether your approach works or not and what alternatives you looked at. Usually, this question should not survive the Triage Review that new questions go through.

Anyway, I think the "standard"/tutorial way to do what you want to achieve would be

```
current_user.admin = true
```

. Hope it helps and have fun at Stackoverflow, but remember to put a lot of love and care into your questions, as many people will read them.

Comment: I need to do current user as admin. So I am trying to update my users table.
' if current_user.admin != true
current_user.update_attributes(:admin => '1')
end '

Comment: `current_user.admin` ||= true would do the trick, but is less explicit. But this has not really anything to do with an "update query".